# Книга на английском по С++/Java

Tags: java, c++, книги

Здравствуйте , вот возник вопрос что дальше читать. Вот только закончил читать Шилдта по Си  , также читал Шилдта по Java (но не закончил). Посоветуйте пожалуйста ,что лучше дальше читать и вообще , стоит ли начинать изучать что-то новое . 
Посоветуйте пожалуйста , желательно книгу на английском .

Comment: > много писать самому

При этом полезно учиться писать сразу правильно. В этом авторы вроде Блоха и помогут. А в качестве справочника и JavaDoc сгодится.

Answer (score 5):

По Java:

- [Bruce Eckel  - Thinking in Java (4th Edition)](http://www.amazon.com/Thinking-Java-Edition-Bruce-Eckel/dp/0131872486/)
- [Joshua Bloch - Effective Java (2nd Edition)](http://www.amazon.com/Effective-Java-Edition-Joshua-Bloch/dp/0321356683)
- [Java Concurrency in Practice](http://www.amazon.com/Java-Concurrency-Practice-Brian-Goetz/dp/0321349601)
- [Joshua Bloch - Java Puzzlers: Traps, Pitfalls, and Corner Cases](http://www.amazon.com/Java%C2%BF-Puzzlers-Traps-Pitfalls-Corner/dp/032133678X/)

По С++, конечно, [Bjarne Stroustrup - The C++ Programming Language](http://www.amazon.com/C-Programming-Language-4th-ebook/dp/B00DUW4BMS). Может быть еще [Andrei Alexandrescu - Modern C++ Design: Generic Programming and Design Patterns Applied](http://www.amazon.com/Modern-Design-Generic-Programming-Patterns/dp/0201704315).

Comment: Александреску не стоит читать людям с небольшим опытом.

Comment: Пока ТС осилит Страуструпа (если осилит), он перестанет быть человеком с небольшим опытом )

Answer (score 5):

Собственно, все хорошие книги по С++ являются переводными

- Bjarne Stroustrup - The C++ Programming Language
- Deitel H. M., Deitel P.J. - C++: How to Program
- Bjarne Stroustrup - Programming: Principles and Practice Using C++
- Andrew Koenig, Barbara E. Moo - Accelerated C++
- Herb Sutter - Exceptional C++

Comment: Principles and Practice большая и нудная.  Лучше вместо нее Майерса Effective STL   и что то там еще у него есть из серии Effective

Answer (score 4):

[Веревка достаточной длины, чтобы выстрелить себе в ногу](http://e-maxx.ru/bookz/files/golub_cord.pdf)
Может оказаться полезной в С++ и мне показалась очень интересно написанной.

Comment: неплохой сборник best practices.

Answer (score 3):

Если Java - Хостманна можно. Правда, подозреваю, многое может повторяться, но... Или документацию на Java вкуривать, она на английском и более полная.

Comment: купил себе оба тома, успел почитать вырезками по паре глав и там точно нет "воды", с нетерпением жду НГ и продолжения:) а шилдт(java) даже рядом не валялся, по С++ его тоже ругают.

Comment: Сам читаю, разбираю, радуюсь. Правда на русском, английский не позволяет читать книги свободно:) Но на документацию хватает